# How to get multiple separate HTML tables to all be the same width as the widest table

Tags: html, css, user-interface, html-table

**Problem:** I have HTML markup to deal with that consists of multiple tables nested inside another table. I would like the "inner tables" to all be the same width. I would also like all of the "inner tables" to be no wider than the width of the widest "inner table" in its natural state.

I do *not* want to simply set the width of all the tables to some fixed percentage, as I do not know in advance what the width of the widest "inner table" should be until the HTML page is actually generated.

[image: Here is a visual example]

<sup><sub>Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Erasene-screen001.png</sub></sup>

I want all tables to be the same width as inner-table-zero. Currently, none of the tables have an assigned width, and that's the way I like it, because I want all inner tables to naturally choose the width of whichever table is widest by default.

**Question:** Is there any CSS or JQuery or Javascript trick anyone knows that will obtain this desired styling?

**Update:** I'm about to delete this question because people seem to want to downvote me for not having a good reason for not wanting 100%. I **do** have a good reason ... I also do not know until runtime *which* table will be the "outermost" table (this is a recursively-generated structure of potentially unlimited depth).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid width: 100%? Is there an actual reason or are you just being stubborn?

Comment: What we need to know is whether you're giving the outer table a specific size or not. You never specified so we assume you didn't.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which one is outer, it just matters if it will have a width or not.

Comment: That's the point, I do not want *any* of the tables to have a width, because I don't know in advance what width it should be. (If i pick 100%, then whatever ends up being the "outermost" will fill the entire page), even if the text by itself is not naturally wide enough to span the whole page.

Comment: drefty, any reason my answer doesn't work for you? I'm not trying to force 100% width down your throat :)

Comment: @Paolo: Sorry, I was a little late :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know of any HTML/CSS tricks to get it done, but since you are open to jQuery...

Assuming all your inner tables have a class of 'inner', you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var largest = 0;
    $('table.inner').each(function() {
        var width = $(this)[0].offsetWidth;
        if(width > largest) {
            largest = width;
        }
    }).width(largest);
});
```

EDIT: updated my answer to use `offsetWidth` instead of jQuery's `width()`, as the latter does not include border, padding, or margins in it. Tested it on IE7, FF, Safari, Opera, and it gives the desired effect.

Comment: I don't know if this will work if the table.inner's are recursive.

Comment: @Paolo: This by itself will not work but offsetWidth is a good idea that no one else seemed to think of. An improvement would be to append a 'depth' integer to the className and use a recursive function to treat each depth-level as a set.

Comment: @dreftymac: is there anyway you could give me a sample HTML code of the nested tables and how they would look like + do you have any control over putting different classes depending on depth? I can edit my answer to accommodate then. Either way, hope it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just set the inner tables to 100% width and let it be limited by the outer table? If it's not the case that your outer table will be limiting the inner tables, then your example isn't doing a very good job of specifying that.

The CSS "trick" you're looking for is:

```
table.inner { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Please see the update for why I specifically asked for anything other than this solution.

Comment: The problem is, I will not know until runtime *which* table will be the "outer table". If I set 100% on *any* table, that one could potentially the "outer" one at runtime. This automatically invalidates the assumption in your explanation.

Comment: But you only had to label them as you wrote them.  Somehow this was not correct but Paolo's was?  Don't they both require a class called "inner" on only some of the tables?

Comment: Not if you surround it with a div

Comment: @MrChrister: Paolo's was the accepted answer not because it was complete but because he came the closest to actually answering what I asked. Paolo's answer becomes more complete if you append a "depth" integer to the className (e.g., inner0, inner1, inner2, etc.), thus treating depths uniquely.

Comment: @d03boy: I tried the surrounding div idea. No Worky (see below). I didn't try table.inner because that clearly will not work because of the recursion problem. Anyway, thanks for your answers and ideas.

Comment: If you find a working example of the answer you should let us know

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to update each table's width according to the widest one. But I have a feeling you're looking for a script-less solution... (right?)

Answer (score 1):

Code the inner tables to all have width=100%, then they will all be as wide as the outer table. If you want all the columns of the inner tables to be the same width, then you'd have to specify those widths on their column headers (or first rows).

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<TITLE>Mike Test</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<table border=1>
  <tr><td>
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>



<table border=1>
  <tr><td>
    <table border=1 width="100%">
      <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <table border=1 width="100%">
      <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can get around width:100%. That is in essence what you are trying to do: set the width of each table to the total width of the containing element, whose width is determined by the widest embedded table in that column.

Edited to add:

If you really want to avoid it at all costs, you can always use prototype to get the actual widths of elements in pixels, and then re-apply the maximum width to all the other elements.
Could probably be done easily using prototype and behaviors.

Answer (score -1):

> I also do not know until runtime which table will be the "outermost" table (this is a recursively-generated structure of potentially unlimited depth).

Do you need to know?

**wrap everything around a div or table**, give it a fixed or percentage width to make it right into your web design, then all the container tables should be set to 100%

```
.content-wrapper { width: 450px; }
table { width: 100%; }

<div id="content-wrapper">
    <!-- all your tables/content/divs/etc -->
</div>
```

that is what everyone does, and that is why in all design elements on code you have DIV's called Wrappers, to get to your point.

Please don't try to re-invent the wheel... everyone does this, you're not the first one.

Comment: The problem is, I want content-wrapper to be as wide as the fattest child table *and no wider than that*. In other words, I want content-wrapper to be as small as possible without it clipping the text of any child table. Your answer assumes 450px which is not what I am asking at all.

Comment: Actually his doesn't assume 450px since he assigns that width to the CLASS content-wrapper and then gives his div an ID of content-wrapper. SO his div really doesn't have a width. And it still works properly.

Comment: @d03boy: Your point about CLASS versus ID is correct, in reality though it was probably just a typo and even if not, it still doesn't work because the 100% causes the tables to span the full width of the page. The outer DIV just blindly expands 100% to accommodate them.

Comment: I see that now. I didn't think the div would expand with them.